# Getting Parse info from a saved Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have an array saved in Parse.  I'm trying to retrieve it using this method...

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
query.whereKey("vid1", containsAllObjectsInArray:[1,2,3,4])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (vid:Array?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if !(error != nil)
    {
        print(vid!)
    }
}
```

I'm printing an empty array.  What I'm looking for is similar to a REST API where I have

```
vid1: element, element, element, element; 
vid2: element, element, element, element; 
vid3: element, element, element...
```

and so on in order for me to use them in tableview cells.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please explain what you hope to achieve using the constraint *containsAllObjectsInArray*

Comment: It was an attempt to get individual elements from my saved array.  Parse documentation has it this way You can also find objects where the key's array value contains each of the values 2, 3, and 4 with the following: "query.whereKey("arrayKey", containsAllObjectsInArray:[2, 3, 4])" , but its not working.

Comment: containsAllObjectsInArray means that you have an array of values [1,2,3,4] and the objects you want to return from the query is only objects that has a "vid1" that also include all of 1,2,3,4. The rest of your questions does not have me believe this is what you're after. Please elaborate on your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  I simply ran the query for user since the only objects one user should have would be vids 1 - 10.  Then I ran a for loop for the items with strings equal to vid1 - vid10. Finally I created public arrays in this view controller and appended them with each element.  Here's my code.....

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
        query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (vid:Array?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if !(error != nil)
            {
                //print(vid!)
                for items in vid!
                {

                    if let myfav1 = items["vid1"] as? NSArray
                    {
                        let id = myfav1[0] as! String
                        let title = myfav1[1] as! String
                        let description = myfav1[2] as! String
                        let image = myfav1[3] as! String
                        self.vidRankArray.append(1)
                        self.vidIdArray.append(id)
                        self.vidTitleArray.append(title)
                        self.vidDescriptionArray.append(description)
                        self.vidImageArray.append(image)
                    }
```

I've tried this before, but evidently had something off coming out of my query, for loop, or items. This works though.